# How to Use Options menu upto GingerBread and Action Bar in Honeycomb and above?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I have seen some of the application which will display Options Menu when they are installed in devices which having GingerBread and below version os. the same apps display action bar in devices which are having HoneyComb and above version os. Now my app has same requirement. How can I achieve this?

This is an [example.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say goodbye to menu button!

This [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) might help you

**UPDATE 1:**

You can still use Menu in Froyo or Honeycomb above.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When user choose an item from action bar or options menu, this callback can still be used by Honeycomb and above

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am ready to say goodbye to menu button but there is no compatibility of action bar provided to pre-gingerbread devices na. my app targets all devices above 2.2 version. So I need to use Menu. How to give support for both things I required

Comment: yes Honeycomb will use the callback but it shouldn't display Options Menu in Honeycomb and above. I want to use Action Bar in Honeycomb and above. As there is no actionbar in pre-Honeycomb devices, I want to use Options Menu over there.

Comment: There's no problem on that, does your app in honeycomb still display option menu instead of actionbar?

Comment: you mean it doesn't display menu in Honeycomb and above version os? I haven't given a try. So I need to code Options Menu for GingerBread and below versions which will not work for Honeycomb and above. So I can add action bar for the above Honeycomb version by putting an if loop check whether app running on above Honeycomb or not? is it right?

Comment: Yes it is, do you have a ``values-v11`` folder?

Comment: yes my project generates it by default but not used yet. Is that such important. Can you suggest any tutorial in this regard.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources